# Java Multi Environment Best Practices Question

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, struts2

I am working in this project with multiple deployments.

The initial idea was to create a single source code for template and customize it for each of the different environments as needed.  However we are now working on the 5th deployment of the template system and the customization are starting to get way out of hand.

I guess I'm just wondering what sort of solutions are out there to maintain source code without running a bunch of "If business is business 1 " statements all throughout code.  We have like 20 more deployments to go through.

We initially thought the customization would only be visual so we set up Ant builds to set the project from template to system specific but for customized logic this was deemed too difficult to maintain so we just implemented a couple "If" statements based on a company code the Ant build sets.

Now the system is getting out of control and I think we really need to implement a widespread solution to clean this mess up.  The project has been going on for like 2.5 years and has another 7 years before projected completion.

```
if (AppCodeConst.SYSTEM_COMPANY_CD.equals(AppCodeConst.BUSINESS_1)) {
} else if (AppCodeConst.SYSTEM_COMPANY_CD.equals(AppCodeConst.BUSINESS_2)) {
} else if (AppCodeConst.SYSTEM_COMPANY_CD.equals(AppCodeConst.BUSINESS_3)) {
} else {
}
```

Comment: You should never be writing conditionals like that in an OO language. That's a procedural way of thinking. Use interfaces with different implementations. `interface Foo { void doThing(); }` `class BusinessOneFoo implements Foo`. Once you've done that, you can think about how to package and deploy it (one spring-centric way might be to switch implementations based on profile).

Comment: There are many ways this could be handled; the best way depends on more information than provided. A trivial `if` statement in no way provides enough info to help, and even if it did, this would boil down to an opinion answer, or too broad. It's *highly* dependent on what kinds of customizations are required, how often/where they're required, the nature of the customizations, etc.

Comment: While I appreciate the input from your comments they aren't really answers nor do they point toward valid references that can expand on the issue.   I understand this is a rather abstract issue but I posted it because I knew something was wrong repeating that it's wrong and saying "there are many ..." Doesn't help.  I didn't post this question without doing any research.